# Optimize sql Query which take too long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

The following sql query is taking to much to return a result

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM List_declarations
WHERE  Id_antenne IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM Service
   WHERE id_direction IN (
      SELECT id_dr
      FROM affectation_service_dr
      WHERE id_service = 15
   )
)
```

How I can do better  ?

Comment: its worrying that this is taking too long to run, can you provide some times and execution plans?

Comment: All the `IN's` can be transformed in `JOINs`. Does not mean it will be super fast still, but you should see some improvement. Next you would need supporting indexes.

Comment: it's taking 37s

Comment: Just guessing - might be db engine specific - but sometimes EXISTS performs better so if you can convert query to use that with join.

Comment: "Never use IN for lists longer than you'd be prepared to write by hand" :) - OK so it doesn't always apply, as some db engines can rewrite IN to be a join equivalent.. But, experience has taught me that some databases perform better with join than in, so i've found it a useful mantra to keep to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everyone proposition but nothing seems to be the solution , the time consumed by the request is still 37s

contemplating the request , I realized that the query within the in clause is executed for every row in table list_declarations which contains a huge amount of data . and the following sql code worked nickel (1s) :

```
declare  @table table( idantenne nvarchar(20))
insert into @table select ID from Service where id_direction in (select id_dr from affectation_service_dr where id_service = 15)
Declare @string AS Nvarchar(MAX) -- It must not be MAX if you have few numbers 
SELECT  @string = COALESCE(@string + ',', '') + idantenne
FROM   @table where idantenne IS NOT NULL
declare @req nvarchar(max)
set @req = 'SELECT * FROM List_declarations Where 1=1  and Id_antenne in (' + @string +' )'
exec (@req)
```

Comment: after this optimizing this my query , it's now 7s and it's still too slow

Comment: this the final query which is too slow : SELECT count(*) FROM List_declarations Where 1=1 and Id_antenne in (1,2,14,15,16,9,13)

Answer (score 1):

I would think of changing the `IN's` to `JOIN's`:

```
select count(*) 
from list_declarations d join service s on d.id_antenne = s.id
                         join affectation_service_dr sdr on sdr.id_dr = s.id_direction
where sdr.id_service = 15
```

Then I would again check performance and see if there are any indexes on the columns used in the where clause and on the foreign keys.

Comment: At least if there are only 1 - 1 relationships.

Comment: @jarlh Do you assert that IN doesn't work with 1:m relationships?

Comment: @CaiusJard, depends on what you want to count.

Comment: Can you give some example values for a and b that would realise IN and JOIN giving a number of rows output in `SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON a = b` vs `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE a IN (SELECT b FROM t2)` ?

Comment: join is taking also 38s

Comment: Try indexing those columns, as adviced by @CaiusJard.

Comment: insert into t1 values (1),  insert into t2 values (1), insert into t2 values (1). (@CaiusJard)

Comment: You have a point there.. I did indeed ask for 1:M and that's what I was given. For M:1 it's fine though (and presumably that's what this case is). I should be careful what I wish for; I might just get it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM 
  List_declarations d
  INNER JOIN Service 
  ON d.Id_antenne = s.id

  INNER JOIN affectation_service_dr a
  s.id_direction = a.id_dr

WHERE 
  a.id_service = 15
```

- it might make a difference, it might not (but it's generally a better way to write a query of this nature)

Of inestimable importance, is to ensure the following are indexed:

```
affectation_service_dr.id_service 
Service.id_direction 
List_declarations.Id_antenne
```

If there are still performance issues that cannot be easily explained by a huge number of rows (e.g. it's taking 38s but it IS returning a count of 20348957389956845) then I recommend you modify your question to include the plan explanation ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-performance-explain.html )

Comment: join  is taking alsi 38s

Comment: I should have made it clear that join isn't necessarily the answer

Comment: SQL server would have converted the query to join behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

if Read Uncommitted data are not a concern here.If it concern then still you can try removing `with (nolock)`

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM List_declarations LD WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  exists (
   SELECT id
   FROM [Service] S WITH (NOLOCK)
   inner join affectation_service_dr dr WITH (NOLOCK)
   on s.id_direction=dr.id_dr
    WHERE ld.Id_antenne=s.id and dr.id_service = 15
   )
```